# How to merge branch and retain the authorship

Tags: git

let's say that my colleage John has created a branch called 'john'. It has 10 committs by John. When it comes to merging back to master they ask me to do merging.

This is what I do

```
git checkout -b john origin/john
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge john --squashed
git add .
git commit -m 'merged branch john'
```

However now what happens is that it is my id against the merged commit. And later people come asking me why did I change certain part of code.

How do I collapse all the comitts in john branch into one commit such that John is the author. I guess git commit interactive can help but could not quite understand.

Answer (score 12):

The issue here is that `git merge --squash` will apply the same changes as a normal merge, but without retaining the merge information. Then, when you commit, it's the same as any commit you make: it's attributed to you. You could change the commit's author information using `git commit --author="Original Author <email@server>"`. See [git-commit(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) for more information on the `--author` switch.

But the question I have is: why are you squashing the merge? Why not just do a non-squashed merge? If anyone does a `git blame`, it will be appropriately attributed to the commit by the original author.

Comment: so that I could easily roll back since after squashed it is one single commit that needs to be rolled back. If I don't squash then it will be  10 comitts to rollback unless there is a better way.

Comment: As noted in mfontani's answer, if you merge --no-ff, a merge commit will be recorded, and if you rollback that one commit, it'll have the same effect as rolling back a squashed commit, but with the added benefit of recording the complete commit history as well.

Comment: one reason to do a squash merge is that sometimes people commit a bunch of broken states to their branch, which makes bisect harder, but the final branch fine, and sometimes the branch only has one author anyways.

Answer (score 9):

You can also `--amend` the authorship afterwards if you already did the merge. like that:

```
git checkout master
git merge my_branch
git commit --amend --author="My Nick <my.adress@email.com>"
git push origin master
```

This works as desired and adds the specified author to the merge commit. Simple as that.

Answer (score 7):

If you do the following:

```
git checkout -b john origin/john
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff john # forces a merge commit to be recorded
```

you'll be able to both both retain the authorship of John's commits *and* be able to revert the merge by reverting the SHA of the merge commit.

Comment: really that's awesome. I guess I should do some testing myself if I commit using git merge --no-ff john then will I get to see 10 committs in my master log from john or will I see one commit as I would see in case of squashed. I don't mind 10 comitts lin the log. my only concern was that I should be able to revert easily.

Comment: You will see all the commits you rebased, but you will be able to undo the merge just by reverting the merge commit.
Furthermore, you keep track of which commits belonged to which branch :)

Comment: I look forward to hearing whether the above worked out for you, and therefore answers your original question.

Comment: I used this. While it does preserve all the history, I had to separately set the author back to the original author: `git commit --amend author=original.guy@company.com --signoff`

Answer (score 7):

The way I have just done this is by squashing via rebase:

```
 git rebase --onto master -i master remote/branch
```

Then in the editor, mark all commits "squash". This yields a single one with the original author attached. Though there really is nothing you gain as opposed to copying the original author into --author. I just felt uncomfortable doing that.

For some reason, my HEAD was detached afterwards, so I reattached master to it via:

```
 git checkout -B master HEAD
```